# AttributeError: 'long' object has no attribute 'save'

Tags: python, django

I got this error when I run my django app.
This is models.py and the last field is cart_count where I got error after adding that field.
models.py

```
class Series(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    tutor = models.ForeignKey(Tutor)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=10000)
    video = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    image = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    GBP = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    USD = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    Euro = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    showcase = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    difficulty = models.CharField(("Difficulty"), max_length=10, choices=DIFFICULTY)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    seo_meta = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    seo_meta_keywords = models.ManyToManyField(Keyword)
    video_filename = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    related_series = models.ManyToManyField("self")
    is_backing_tracks = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    enable_lesson_previews = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    cart_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

my views.py code
views.py

```
def add_to_cart_series(request, sid):
    # TODO have to redirect to cart page if the series already bought.
    series = Series.objects.get(id=sid)
    count=series.cart_count
    count+=1
    count.save()
    print count
```

output error

```
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:'long' object has no attribute 'save'
```

Comment: Yes. Why are you calling `save()` on the count?

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that count is an integer variable and you don't have the method `save()` for it. If you want to increase the attribute `series.cart_count` of the object `series` by one, you just do

```
series.cart_count += 1
series.save()
```

without need of the variable count (assuming that this is your expected behavior).

Answer (score 0):

You are calling save() method on long object which should be called on queryset, because save() method is not defined on long object you are getting this error, save() method is the part of Django ORM which is use to save new entry or update existing one, so, this should go like this,

simply replace

`count=series.cart_count
count+=1
count.save()`

with

`series.cart_count += 1
series.save()`

Answer (score 0):

In your code count is just an integrer, actually you are supposed to save the object. Here the object is series.

```
def add_to_cart_series(request, sid):
  # TODO have to redirect to cart page if the series already bought.
  series = Series.objects.get(id=sid)
  series.cart_count += 1
  series.save()
```